# infinite while loop and struct

Tags: c

This is piece of code. Basically, it is counting number of students in the list in first "while" part and than allocating according to counted. and save it to struct.
But the problem is: first "while" is running as an infinite loop?

```
int t=0;

FILE *exam;

struct str_examrecords_table
{
    int id_number;
    char result;
};


void Load_examrecords_table(struct str_examrecords_table *examrecords_table)
{
    char temporary_char;
    int temporary_int, i=0;

    exam=fopen("examrecords.odt","r");

    if(exam!=NULL)
    {
        while(fscanf(exam, "%d %c", &temporary_int, &temporary_char)!=EOF)  
        t++;

        examrecords_table = (struct str_examrecords_table *) malloc(sizeof(struct str_examrecords_table) * t);

        while(fscanf(exam, "%d %c", &examrecords_table[i].id_number, &examrecords_table[i].result)!=EOF)    
        i++;
    }
    else exit(1);

    for(int j=0; j<i; j++)  
    printf("%d %c \n", examrecords_table[i].id_number, examrecords_table[i].result);

    fclose(exam);
}


int main()
{
    struct str_examrecords_table   *examrecords_table;
    Load_examrecords_table(examrecords_table);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) :

> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.

And

> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

So change it to:

`while(fscanf(exam, "%d %c", &temporary_int, &temporary_char) == 2)`

Comment: Agree, but I think you meant `==` not `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) documentation, the return value of `fscanf` indicates the number of read items, not a possible end of file.